# How to make the profile page editable for users and i want to save those data after editing (vue.js + laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

i`m making a web application for a company and in the profile page i want user to edit details and add some more details and save them. i tried many ways and they are not working

i want user to edit these first name and last name which we get from the database after login

```
      <v-dialog v-model="dialog">
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
            <span class="headline">Edit User</span>
          </v-card-title>

          <v-card-text>
            <v-container grid-list-md>
              <v-layout wrap>
                <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
                  <v-text-field v-model="user.firstName" label="First Name"></v-text-field>
                </v-flex>

                <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
                  <v-text-field v-model="user.lastName" label="Last Name"></v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
            </v-container>
          </v-card-text>

          <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>

            <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat>Cancel</v-btn>

            <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat>Save</v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
```

Comment: Can you provide more information as to Why its not working? e.g. the response code. If you are using vue.js to post this data are you posting it to a api route with some sort of token to bypass the csrf validation?

Comment: no i don`t have an idea to do it. i searched in the internet also i was failed to do it. yes i`m passing with api routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have to send a http request to backend and save data using the response. Refer this tutorial for more details.
 vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html

I have done using this method

Answer (score 2):

Create a [form](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/form-validation.html) which sends a POST request to some endpoint and updates the data based on what the user has written.

Comment: i used a dialog box here